# What will be used here gerund or past participle

Tags: grammar

I blew an deflated balloon laid/laying on the street

Comment: Here's something that might help: *lying* is intransitive, like "I am lying in the street."  *laying* is transitive, like "I am laying the balloon in the street."

Answer (score 1):

I think it'd be "lying", if you just came across a balloon in the street and didn't know how it got there. It could also be "the balloon someone laid in the street", if you watched somebody put it there. But I'd go with "lying".

The rest of your sentence doesn't make any sense. Did you blow *up* the balloon? If so, it wasn't just lying in the street anymore. Did you blow it away? Also, you'd need to use the article *a* instead of *an*, because the next word starts with a consonant.

Try: "I blew up the deflated balloon I found lying in the street."

Comment: What if i write i blew up the deflated balloon lying on the street. What would that mean?

Comment: @user236989 "blow up" is a synonym for "inflate". So, it would mean you found a deflated balloon in the street and you inflated it.